# Map deeply nested object return type of a function depending on shape of input parameter

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to achieve some complex typing for a library I'm working on, but I'm not even sure what I'm trying to achieve is doable with TypesScript.

The library I'm working on is a schema & promise-based form generator built with Vue & TS, that handles for you UI rendering & mounting, validation, etc., and lets you collect data from users in a purely functional way.

Here's a very basic example for you to understand:

```js
const { formData, isCompleted } = await formApi.createForm({
  fields: [
    {
        "key": "email",
        "label": "Email address",
        "type": "text",
        "required": true,
        "validators": { "email": isEmail, },
        "size": 8
    },
    {
        "key": "password",
        "label": "Password",
        "type": "password",
        "required": true
    },
  ]
})
```

Here, formData will be equal to: `{ email: "...", password: "..." }`

What I want to achieve is to type FormData to be equal in this case to `{ email: string, password: string }` instead of the `{ [key: string]: any }` type that I currently return.

This is a very simple example, but the library can generate really complex forms, supports deeply nested objects/arrays fields, conditional rendering based on other fields, and a lot of customisation.

**EDIT**

After seeing replies, I understand that depending on the complexity of the schema, the actual TS implementation will differ a lot.

Considering this, here's a more advanced example that includes a lot of the aspects the lib is able to handle (Live stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-xyzwq9?file=src/components/SimpleDependency.vue):

```js
const { isCompleted, formData } = await createForm({
  fullScreen: 'true md:false',
  title: 'ADVANCED FORM SCHEMA EXAMPLE',
  gridSize: 8,
  fieldSize: '8 md:4',
  fields: [
    {
      key: 'firstName',
      label: 'First name',
      type: 'text',
      required: true,
    },
    {
      key: 'lastName',
      label: 'Last name',
      type: 'text',
      required: true,
    },
    {
      key: 'email',
      label: 'Email',
      type: 'text',
      size: 8,
    },
    {
      key: 'address',
      label: 'Address',
      type: 'object',
      size: 8,
      fields: [
        {
          key: 'street',
          label: 'Street',
          type: 'text',
          required: true,
        },
        {
          key: 'zipCode',
          label: 'ZIP Code',
          type: 'text',
          required: true,
        },
        {
          key: 'city',
          label: 'City',
          type: 'text',
          required: true,
        },
        {
          key: 'country',
          label: 'Country',
          type: 'text',
          required: true,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'skills',
      label: 'Dev skills',
      type: 'select',
      fieldParams: {
        multiple: true,
        writable: true,
      },
      options: [
        'Vue',
        'Angular',
        'React',
        'ExpressJs',
        'NestJs',
        'Fastify',
        'Typescript',
        'C#',
        'Swift',
        'Go',
        'Rust',
      ].map((value) => ({ label: value, value })),
    },
    {
      key: 'hasProExperiences',
      label: 'Has prior professional experiences',
      type: 'checkbox',
      size: 8,
    },
    {
      key: 'professionalExperiences',
      label: 'Professional experiences',
      type: 'array',
      size: 8,
      dependencies: ['hasProExperiences'],
      condition: ({ hasProExperiences }) => !!hasProExperiences,
      headerTemplate: (_, index) => `JOB ${index + 1}`,
      fields: [
        {
          key: 'company',
          label: 'Company',
          type: 'text',
          required: true,
        },
        {
          key: 'job',
          label: 'Job title',
          type: 'text',
          required: true,
        },
        {
          key: 'period',
          label: 'Job period',
          type: 'daterange',
          required: true,
          size: 8,
        },
        {
          key: 'description',
          label: 'Job description',
          type: 'textarea',
          size: 8,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

And from this complex schema, here's the type definition I want to assign to formData in output :

```js
interface ExpectedType {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  address: {
    street: string;
    zipCode: string;
    city: string;
    country: string
  };
  skills: string[] // "multiple" prop set to true on the field, so multiple values selected
  hasProExperiences: boolean;
  professionalExperiences?: Array<{  // Could be undefined because rendered & included in form state only if 'hasProExperiences' is true
    company: string; 
    job: string;
    period: [string, string];
    description: string;
  }>
}
```

Comment: Challenge accepted. I notice you've got a `writable` field parameter. Does this mean the other fields are read-only?

Comment: Not exactly, I'll rename this prop later, it means you can add select options in addition to the default options defined on the select (In a "tag" way").

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on a solution, although the one by @TobiasS works as well.
It's quite an eyesore but it was designed to be more "extensible".

```
type InputTypeMap = {
    text: string;
    textarea: string;
    daterange: [number, number];
    checkbox: boolean;
};

type AddUndefinedIfDependent<T, F extends FormField> = "dependencies" extends keyof F ? T | undefined : T;

type DataFrom<F extends FormField[]> = {
    [K in F[number]["key"]]:
        Extract<F[number], { key: K }> extends infer Field extends FormField
            ? Field["type"] extends keyof InputTypeMap
                ? AddUndefinedIfDependent<InputTypeMap[Field["type"]], Field>
                : Field["type"] extends "object"
                    ? "fields" extends keyof Field
                        ? Field["fields"] extends FormField[]
                            ? AddUndefinedIfDependent<DataFrom<Field["fields"]>, Field>
                            : never
                        : never
                    : Field["type"] extends "array"
                        ? "fields" extends keyof Field
                            ? Field["fields"] extends FormField[]
                                ? AddUndefinedIfDependent<DataFrom<Field["fields"]>[], Field>
                                : never
                            : never
                        : Field["type"] extends "select"
                            ? "options" extends keyof Field
                                ? Field["options"] extends { value: any }[]
                                    ? "fieldParams" extends keyof Field
                                        ? Field["fieldParams"] extends { multiple: true }
                                            ? AddUndefinedIfDependent<Field["options"][number]["value"][], Field>
                                            : AddUndefinedIfDependent<Field["options"][number]["value"], Field>
                                        : never
                                    : never
                                : never
                            : never
            : never;
} extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

Essentially it's just logic to get the correct type out. What's different is the use of another type to map input types to the output type. For example, `daterange` outputs `[number, number]` in `InputTypeMap`. This makes it easy to add more input types if you need to. Note that types that are affected by other things in the field should go in the `DataFrom` type.

If you're wondering about this line here:

```
} extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

It's to simplify the output type so you don't get `DataFrom<...>` in tooltips.

And here's how you would define your function:

```
function createForm<I extends FormInit>(
    init: Narrow<I>
): Promise<{
    isCompleted: false;
    formData: undefined;
} | { // using discriminated union so that when isCompleted is false, formData is undefined
    isCompleted: true;
    formData: DataFrom<I["fields"]>;
}> {
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wglVlN)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this "simple example" could look like this:

```
async function createForm<T extends string>(arg: {
  fields: { 
    key: T,
    label: string,
    type: string,
    required: boolean,
    size?: number
  }[]
}): Promise<{ formData: { [K in T]: string }, isCompleted: any }> {
  return {} as any
}
```

We can store the contents of the `key` field inside the generic type `T` and use it later to build a mapped type for the return type.

But if the schemas get more complex, this may have  to be completely rewritten with more/different generic types.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FACghgzgngdgxgAhASgQXgHwIN7AQuAexggBccEAzQgJwFsARMUsAGgQEsIBhQugBwA2AU1LCAJggC%206BGADuYDuTg1hzYQDFadELnz5KHYYPEQAXAgDaeA-n13HAIgDWwqE8tPhdJYKesto4GToJgAEYmnghOAKK%20HIJy4uJqEBABQcExpFD8wtFOYgAepJnZIWoAjgCuHGri0aQ0NcKBFfhOEBwAXgWWABxZ%20FLtjg4Vru6F-JAQ8rSNY5Nhkf5eAApzCzRLw865%20TPbi%20UdTtV1DU0twvujWQC6tlLIwK-An5CwiJQ18KQOMQCGoNNp6AAeAAqCGEpWEMDMCDINA4MAA5hhwDR0ZYHEYTGY8Qgsm4oJYocsEKsTJYUWj0VTDsI6c0GVTLvUJJZwoRCCIwDAqd0%20gB%20SwwGp0SI0F5WZ6vSwbGh8LjCCHYKg6JgsYlWADSnBgCChj1ZqIx0nYXF4AhEYnElkFUGkWAcalINRoxuwMkgchgUHeQA)

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a solution for your edited details.

```
type FormInfo<N> = {
  key: N
  label: string
  type: N
  required?: boolean
  size?: number
  fieldParams?: {
    multiple: boolean,
    writable: boolean,
  },
  condition?: (...args: any) => any
  fields?: FormInfo<N>[]
}
```

The type `FormInfo` is used to describe the schema of the `createForm` argument. I left out properties which were not relevant to the question.

```
type ResolveFormType<K extends FormInfo<any>> =  
  K["type"] extends "checkbox"
    ? boolean
    : K["type"] extends "object"
      ? K["fields"] extends infer U extends FormInfo<any>[]
        ? FormInfoReturnType<U[number]>
        : never
      : K["type"] extends "select"
        ? K["fieldParams"] extends { multiple: true }
          ? string[]
          : string
        : K["type"] extends "array"
          ? K["fields"] extends infer U extends FormInfo<any>[]
            ? FormInfoReturnType<U[number]>[]
            : never
          : K["type"] extends "daterange"
            ? [string, string]
            : string
```

`ResolveFormType` takes an object from the `fields` and evaluates the type based on the `type` property.

```
type FormInfoReturnType<T extends FormInfo<any>> = UnionToIntersection<{
  [K in T as K["condition"] extends (...args: any) => any ? never : K["key"]]: 
    ResolveFormType<K>
} | {
  [K in T as K["condition"] extends (...args: any) => any ? K["key"] : never]?: 
    ResolveFormType<K>
}>
```

`FormInfoReturnType` recursively goes through the `fields` and determines which properties should be optional.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object
  ? T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: ExpandRecursively<O[K]> } : never
  : T;
```

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | object | undefined | void | null | {};

async function createForm<T extends FormInfo<N>, N extends Narrowable>(arg: {
  fields: T[]
}): Promise<{ isCompleted: any, formData: ExpandRecursively<FormInfoReturnType<T>> } > {
  return {} as any
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FACghgzgngdgxgAhASgQXgHwIN7DgexggBccEBLCAYXwFsAHAGwFNjmATAGgQDN8AnWgBEwxMAgC%206BGADuYcqTj9mo5gDEBtELgS9yzRuwgAuBAG1gevbut6A1syhmA5D3L8SAOTC1mLzis7BEYwACNDV3UPEgQYX39A4IRiKHpmVzYAD2IAoLsVAEcAVw8OM2J%20YuYk6wlam3zrR2cEF1DvBLzk0IjGVwAZSFJ4v27g1PTM5hzxguYSsvYKqpqm%20qbbOxbXZloFRjnrXsi2gFF98kOG60mMtuzcm70IcgAve4AOG427LeanK4wOx2CoIBAjnoTv02gBBEFgiHPFJpe4ufBhABWzDgTyaL3eX2R7kMxjMlmSjUpANaLhIKlYkOC0NcAGVKsxGci7HdprNudYiqUVMsUqsBb9Kf9kjs2m9yPQaOxEvjmeFTi4AFoASQACgglSrqXpeQ8ZnjjQghUsVtUJQLpcFZS44IooEy7Cy2lQ3R7bqi%20RbjdaRba1tTJclHdtAW0CMUYJV3QKoeqYS4aAmk36TQGzfzVfNFqGxXbC5JkQBdH43R3OiD2K6MJGqr0uITMABuCAbTZbyVNdMMOKDdhJRl1YH4vlMOHLtGKjGICpYYYFsn4inCq9L4eCkYrm1VzoAFpBdfx8GcsulN8x4Mx%202q%20q4ABKQBD0TcCT%20XniP15CDARgEBmW8DAfJ8eTzF0TxxewwnwLImVeD4zG%20dZa2PWMXC-fB-3BcggMYa9wPvOBHyZNsL3wgCiPiECwOYO9IKZAgYHYRR6LMHQEDPCAaNI5iIIoiBJFQTAEAAQik-jBJvYTyMfZFBynadk1VVCiVVccyQsctoxpVwCAYMAYA0y02xoUzzJzFEpnzUdKRDcpd3tAzywcHDMQxOy2wAKQxFJFBYOzB0eOyXNFSoywjB1PIQZ1wPwdg-LTVxArCT9hJSsKYPYNRpxgABzI1gwWYVXJivdqS09D3OpQyvNpZUIGUBVl0INKXzaTKEFa9r6E6mAPXC80p1UOy6oQDC4tVatMKCBaJGQABuYAVuAYA7gQTRBG1GA%20AAHi8LA0DnZqzC8IIvXpcgSqCU1rr0KKAH4zEQ-AWDMoItPeuJiloCJ%20CCXTJ2nWgIH%20-4FyXFd7k%2076YBuDctzCHdEdUZGgkldjOOG-6QAAOhJqditnMyoAkrBKdBgwjChsw9toA7jtO8xKw2radoAJUfL7Ow0LQABVUSOgBpUCcnvYxdq0Vn8COymMDOvQgnF8wACI7k1yspbYDixM1uA4LgBCkM1ppXoQTGfrsMwNe11Fdf1mWjYxbFcUt5Jrcd3SIBd803YoQ7mIQABVV3Dbl-bDsV5WOfLa3mYVvniGKfgYFF9IjvD8wYEB4HKwwcszBgLtmNVB2tZ1vWg%20jzWIGHL2k4QP36fYcGZ0D6Xo%20wBBYeXJh7mqyQEutu6SsTy0zEn4rS7bmvnbr3vZc1tSwCgb3jV9rX-Z7g3Zfu-9%20AjqPZZTuOlfMjBp8tBBk-luO04zrOxbzgugeY4u75nuIK5Bn-R2tdz5GwKmwIqpVt6WmtuYOe3A56c3vggWelR7rz22qiGOLNn6sFftnZgR1hagOwQra%20UAVbSHDjAeiwt8AHQgU3XE9Ejq2HMJLe6CBiEfkdnjLihAD7B2JqTfg5MzCU2pjIcyD9-6C1PtXTWLRdaVjME0PmEABZC0EAQiWJcpAAB8LoWA4TALhMgxK8MIPjeigjo7CKJmTCm5lJGUxkY7JResy4AMrP9NR-NGCC2Zjo8WeiS6YPSBHGhhA6EMOYkw4audVZBBAJHeustXHWxAPYMw4dkCYE7Pgcg7AUGyOYqgNJYkQBZLMMfMO2o8kYAKUU1A1ttQlPLnI7mWDSJmXYHzOAGdXiC0YFAIhqtiEVIQB7EcQRrYTNXmJWpp8ADyMj%207sJDolJw%20EEDLJUQgHpHF%20mDPIMM0Zyz2HF0kO0gBQQzDC3WuE5gCAfD8EvPIdGzzzpzwQIYz%20wNfk23wF9LGgLoBAy%20oC6ZuJAUJmVO4cuxTDFNKRQDRgIFDHYAkI8yAsBEA8ATMwwgCBlCqDYMzIhJDL5swwNwLwJDXnvO3MwDA4BRFmFsP7e5icVpmBorQSghD%206UGssPNgopKbcD4IIEQYgzCHL6TiE5ZyjrUvwC-TOOjhaUKkFgWwKh06ZxwFID8tMJBAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I kinda understand better what the approach should be to solve my case, but seeing your explanation, I provided a much more complete schema example (plus live vers. on stackblitz) and added those to the main post

Comment: `return null!` is another way of returning whatever is the return type. It might not be as explicit but it's definitely shorter!

Comment: @kelly - That's nice! Im gonna use that one in the future.

Comment: TobiasS. @kelly Thank you guys a lot for taking the time for this! There's a lot for me to learn on those answers!

I'll play around with both and try to really understand what's going on there. Thanks again for the time spent to help